# TypeError : object of type 'bool' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
store_id = 1
acc_id = str(store_id)
print("type of acc_id is ", type(acc_id))

x = len(acc_id)
print(x)

if len(acc_id == 1):
    acc_id += '000' + acc_id
```

**Output:**

```
 type of acc_id is  <class 'str'>
 1
 TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

Why am I getting this error when `acc_id` is clearly a string?

Comment: `if len(acc_id) == 1` instead of `if len(acc_id == 1)`?

Comment: You can do away with the conditional altogether: `acc_id = f'{store_id:04}'`

Comment: Thanks @chepner I'll try it. What is this called so I can read up further?

Comment: It's an f-string literal, introduced in Python 3.6. Older versions can use the `format` method to the same effect: `acc_id = '{:04}'.format(store_id)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not checking the length of `acc_id` correctly.

Correct is `len(acc_id) == 1`.

So the updated code will be:

```
store_id = 1
acc_id = str(store_id)
print("type of acc_id is ", type(acc_id))

x = len(acc_id)
print(x)

if len(acc_id) == 1:
    acc_id += '000' + acc_id
print(acc_id)
```

`acc_id` is now `10001`.

The reason why you got the error is:

- acc_id = '1' before if.
- acc_id == 1 gives `False` because `str` and `int` are not same type of operands
- len(False) gives `TypeError` because there is no `len()` on bool type.